# How to avoid text slight offset while using "text-align: center" in Chromium-based browsers?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a page using pure HTML and CSS. I have noticed that, when two elements are next to each other and the one on the right is displayed as `inline-block`, if `text-align: center` is set while having a fixed width, there is a slight offset in the text, only when the one on the left has specific widths.

Here's a demo I've set up: https://jsfiddle.net/jkswLunt/115/. 
Please try changing the contents of the element on the left (adding/removing characters) and notice the problem goes away in some widths. Where's a [side by side comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMr5B.png) and where's the [result in the page I'm making](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yyqk.png). The effect is almost unnoticeable but it's bothering me.

```css
body {
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}

#l {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#r {
  margin-left: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<span id="l">iiiiiiii</span><span id="r">i</span>
```

This happened to me only on Chrome, MS Edge (the one made with Chromium) and the Electron renderer (uses Chromium). Tested on Firefox and does not happen, so I believe it's a Chromium problem.

After searching for a while, I didn't find any information about this. I've also tried wrapping a div around the element on the right, transferring all the properties to it, but the problem persists.

**Is there any way to work around this?**

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: You might want to try adding `* {box-sizing:border-box;}` to `*` or to `body` or to the divs inside your container or etc  I usually add `* {position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}` at the top of every css file as a css reset.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks. I've added the code.

Comment: @cssyphus I've added `{position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}` to the `body` and the problem unfortunately persists.

Comment: If you added those CSS params to the body, then that CSS would affect only the body tag itself (other tags may inherit but not all). Try adding `*{position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box;}`  just to see if it solves the problem.  Then, you can fine-tune the solution if needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve the problem. Still offset 1 pixel to the right. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you have given `#r` a `height`. Whereas `#l` does not have `height`. Remove the `height` from `#r`.

```css
body {
  font-family: Sans-serif;
}

#l {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#r {
  margin-left: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  /*   height: 12px; */
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<span id="l">iiiiiiii</span><span id="r">i</span>
```

Check it in action on Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/ExNNmQJ

Comment: This did not solve the issue. Setting the color of `#r` to red made it less perceptible but it's still there.

Comment: @Tom4nt See this: https://cdpn.io/manaskhandelwal1/debug/RwoogpL/vWARwGRnqqBk zoom to 500%. You will not see it. you are just feeling it I have tested it. And if you don't believe it, give `#l` a `background-color` and then compare them.

Comment: Changing zoom levels hides the issue. I forgot to mention that in the question. But with 100% zoom, the result differs between Chrome and Firefox. That's why I believe this is a rendering issue.

Comment: @Tom4nt For me the browser says `16px` height for both.

Comment: The height is as expected. My problem is the horizontal centering of the character in `#r`.